# Как переопределить метод validate?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
class ProductSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    discount = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=[0, 10, 15, 20, 30, 50])

    def validate(self, data):
        if data['discount'] not in [0, 10, 15, 20, 30, 50]:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(f"invalid discount")
    
        return super().validate(data)
```

Есть такой код и по идее, когда серверу передать невалидный discount, то должна быть ошибка

```
{
    "discount": [
        "invalid discount"
    ]
}
```

но у меня почему-то другая:

```
{
    "discount": [
        "\"203\" is not a valid choice."
    ]
}
```

На месте 203 может быть любое другое неверное число

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй такой вариант:

```
class ProductSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    discount = serializers.ChoiceField()

    def validate(self, data):
        if data['discount'] not in [0, 10, 15, 20, 30, 50]:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(f"invalid discount")
    
        return super().validate(data)
```